# How to add UIPasteContol button in Xcode for target below 16.0?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to include UIPasteControl in my storyboard, but I'm encountering an error as depicted in the image below, stating "Paste Control before iOS 16.0." This is happening because my Xcode project's target version is lower than iOS 16.0.

Is there a way to integrate UIPasteControl without altering the target iOS version?

[image]

Comment: `UIPasteControl` doesn't exist prior to iOS 16.0. You can conditionally add it in code but you can't add it via storyboard.